# Converting JSON to DataFrame yields error

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON file in the following structure:

```
{"0":"bla bla bla bla", "1":"bla bla bla bla", "2":"..."}
```

I'm loading it with my python program as follows:

```
import json
with open('./json/articles1.json') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

Next, I'd like to convert it to a `DataFrame`. I've tried both:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.read_json(data)
```

But they both produce the error `DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])

    print(df)
```

This prints

```
                 0                1    2
 0  bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla  ...
```